# placeholder in profile specific yml file not resolving from external yml file

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, spring-profiles

I am defining profile specific properties in application-{profilename}.yml file which is inheriting common values from application.yml file .Both  filers are placed in classpath root config directory location.

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8081
  servlet:
    context-path: /extconfigpro
  

    spring:
      jpa:
        show-sql: true
        hibernate:
          naming:
            implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl
            physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
        properties:
          hibernate:
            format_sql: true
            use_sql_comments: true
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
      config:
        name: jdbc,application
        location: classpath:/config/,file:///E:/Springboot/ExternalConfig/
```

**application-test.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: test
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      
com:
  example:
    externalconfignprofile:
      datasource:
        driverClassName: ${test.jdbc.driverClassName}
        jdbcUrl: ${test.jdbc.url}
        username: ${test.jdbc.username}
        password: ${test.jdbc.password}
```

I am creating the datasource while trying to read placeholder values in profile specific yml file form jdbc.yml

**jdbc.yml**

```
test:
  jdbc:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: root123
```

But it is not reading the values from the jdbc.yml file. I also defined one external profile specific file i.e. jdbc-test.yml from there also it is not reading and giving me an error.

```
Failed to bind properties under 'com.example.externalconfignprofile.datasource' to javax.sql.DataSource:

    Property: com.example.externalconfignprofile.datasource.driver-class-name
    Value: ${test.jdbc.driverClassName}
```

Creating datasource as shown below

```
@ConfigurationProperties("com.example.externalconfignprofile.datasource")
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
```

When I am keeping profile specific config in a single application yml file as shown below

```
server:
  port: 8081
  servlet:
    context-path: /extconfigpro
  
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      naming:
        implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
        use_sql_comments: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

      
---

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile:
      - dev
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      
com:
  example:
    externalconfignprofile:
      datasource:
        jdbcUrl: ${dev.jdbc.url}
        driverClassName: ${dev.jdbc.driverClassName}
        username: ${dev.jdbc.username}
        password: ${dev.jdbc.password}
        
---

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile:
      - test
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      
com:
  example:
    externalconfignprofile:
      datasource:
        jdbcUrl: ${test.jdbc.url}
        driverClassName: ${test.jdbc.driverClassName}
        username: ${test.jdbc.username}
        password: ${test.jdbc.password}
```

**Then everything is working fine and placeholder is getting resolved but with profile specific files it is not.**

Please help.Thanks

Comment: If it is profile specific, why are you defining a separate jdbc.yml file, move your props from jdbc.yml to application-test.yml. By this, when you enable test profile, it will pick those props properly

Comment: I am keeping it external because i dont want to touch my application-test yml again and again if in the future i need to change the values

Comment: Its ok to keep in external file. I dont recommend that way. Anyways,  your configuration works by reading the props using @ConfigurationProperties. But this way, it works in regardless of which profile is being invoked. To make it profile specific, include those props inside application-test.yml. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please check my edited question and can give your observation. Thank you